# How, using Pyomo, can I create indexed VarList?

Tags: python, pyomo

I understand that `VarList` is used to add variables on the fly in `Pyomo`.  But I've never seen a VarList that allows adding variables "on-the-fly" with indices.

Below I've shown the actual and desired behavior:

```
import pyomo.environ as pe

### actual behavior
m = pe.ConcreteModel()
m.x = pe.VarList()
for i in range(2):
    for j in range(2):
        new_v = m.x.add()

print(list(m.x._index_set))
```

```
### desired behavior
m = pe.ConcreteModel()
m.x = pe.VarList()
for i in range(2):
    for j in range(2):
        new_v = m.x.add((i,j))

print(list(m.x._index_set))
### ideally this would print: [(0,0), (1,0), (0,1), (1,1)]
```

Such a feature would allow me to access the `VarList` in the future like so:  `m.x[i,j]`.

I've seen this question: [Pyomo and VarList - generate variables automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72309093), but it doesn't use VarList in the answer, and therefore won't support adding variables on the fly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that you cannot create indexed `VarList` components.  The reasons boil down to how Pyomo implements indexing sets: for an "indexed VarList," you really want a Set of independent Sets (which Pyomo supports) - but you would want to index the Var by the set of sets (which Pyomo currently does not support for a number of reasons).

That said, you can get (almost exactly) the behavior you want by indexing a Var with a non-finite Set:

```py
>>> m = ConcreteModel()
>>> m.x = Var(PositiveIntegers, PositiveIntegers, dense=False)
>>> m = ConcreteModel()
>>> m.x = Var(NonNegativeIntegers, NonNegativeIntegers, dense=False)
>>> for i in range(2):
...     for j in range(2):
...         new_v = m.x[i,j] = 0
...
>>> m.x.pprint()
x : Size=4, Index=x_index
    Key    : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
    (0, 0) :  None :     0 :  None : False : False :  Reals
    (0, 1) :  None :     0 :  None : False : False :  Reals
    (1, 0) :  None :     0 :  None : False : False :  Reals
    (1, 1) :  None :     0 :  None : False : False :  Reals
```

Comment: Two comments/questions:  1). the line `new_v = m.x[i,j] = 0` doesn't mess up the model when solving?  (i.e. it doesn't bias the solution or anything).  2). Now that I know this trick, why would I ever need to use `VarList`?

Comment: RE 1) It depends on the solver: MIP solvers tend to ignote the initial point from the model (unless you explicitly tell them to warmstart), whereas nonlinear solvers are *very* sensitive to initial point (and you should *always* initialize your variables for NL solvers).  RE 2) `VarList` is mostly kept around for backwards compatibility, as it predated support for nonfinite indexing sets.